# Flutter android build error Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, duplicates, exoplayer

I got this error when "flutter run" command.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  **Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.**

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: **Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper** found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.17.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.0) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.15.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.15.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

I am not sure the reason, googled but can't find the solution. please help me.
Thanks.

1. I tried "flutter clean" and "flutter pubcache clean"
   "flutter pub get"
   "flutter run"
   but it didn't help me.
2. I checked gradle.properties file, there are
   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true

Who could help me to build this without error?

pubspec.yaml file

environment:
sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1
youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0
smooth_star_rating: 1.1.1

assets_audio_player: ^3.0.4+1

http: ^0.13.4

firebase_auth: ^3.3.12

firebase_core: ^1.14.0
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.10

flutter_html: ^2.2.1
url_launcher: ^6.0.20
connectivity: ^3.0.6
share_plus: ^4.0.3
fluttertoast: ^8.0.9